# How to interpret Java generics like <T> T , <T,V> Query<T> , Class<T>?

Tags: java, generics

There is Java API: [Morphia](http://morphia.googlecode.com/svn/site/morphia/apidocs/com/google/code/morphia/Morphia.html)

class Morphia defines method like:

```
<T> T fromDBObject(Class<T> entityClass, com.mongodb.DBObject dbObject)
```

Can some one explain what `<T> T and Class<T>` means? Is the method returning a class of type T in a collection?

Another API on Inteface DataStore:

```
<T,V> Query<T> find(Class<T> clazz, String property, V value) 

What <T,V> Query<T> means? Is the method returning an object of type Query that is then surrounded by collection `<T,V>` and `<T>`. This part is very confusing.
```

Is it correct to say whenever angle bracket `(< > )` is involved, it always means a Java collection is involved?

Sorry I forgot to mark some content in this question as code otherwise SO was escaping changing entire meaning of the question and hence the 2 answers by @Vash and @fiver are in accordance to the question before this edit.

Thanks for pointing to some tutorials out there but please provide specifc answer from your expertise in Java generics to the question which will then help me to understand the tutorials better.

Comment: There are plenty of generic tutorials out there. Read those. And no, generics are not only used for collections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you see < >, this means generics class - not just collection.

Class is just an example of a generic class: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

T in the declaration means object of any type (T is the type).

So the DBFromObject method is a generic method, where the generic type is denoted with T, which returns an object of this generic type T and accepts a parameter of type `Class<T>`.

Comment: in the returning part of fromDBObject method, what is the difference between <T> and T? How to understand it?

Comment: <T> specifies the name you want to give for your unknown type for this declaration. T is the return type of the function. It could have been: `<T> List<T> SomeFunction(T parameter) { return null; }`

Comment: if I am invoking this method by passing first argument as String.class, then we can think of the returning part as <String> String, but it seem to strange, we want return to be String, where the returning part should only declared as T, isn't?

Comment: If you pass String.class, then the T will be inferred to be String, so the result type should be String. <T> is just a way to specify that the function is generic - it has no other meaning.

Comment: What about something like `Class<V>`? What's the meaning of V there?

Answer (score 8):

Generics are not limited to collections but collections are good examples to understand why you need generics and how you can use them.

Assume that you create a new `List` object and you know it will only contain specific type of objects (e.g., `MyClass` objects). If you could somehow specify it in your code and it can be checked automatically then you can make sure that no other type of object will be inserted to this list. Moreover when other developers read your code, they easily understand that this list contains only `MyClass' objects.

Generics let us to include such information in our code without rewriting the `List` class. In fact, `List` functionality is independent from the type of objects it includes. So to create your own `List` you write this code:

```
         List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
```

Now you can imagine cases where more than one generic type can be specified. A good example of this case is `Map` class. You can define the types of keys and values. So you see `<K,V>` in the `Map` class declaration (`Map<K,V>`).

In addition to Classes, generics can also be used in method/constructor declaration. In your example:

```
         <T,V> Query<T> find(Class<T> clazz, String property, V value)
```

There is a method which has two generic types T and V and you can specify them (or they can be inferred by compiler) when you call the method. Here, `<T,V>` in the declaration explicitly indicates this method feature.

Comment: Can u explain exactly what <T,V> Query<T> means? Is the method returning object of type Query in a collection map in which key is of type T and value is of type V?

Comment: It returns a Query<T>. It has not anything to do with collections. <T,V> only indicates that the method has two generic types: T and V. one of them appeared in Query<T> and Class<T>, the other appeared as an argument type (V value).

Answer (score 0):

The `Query` and [Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) are Java class.

The `<T>` mean that some generic parameter T will be used.

Please read the [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf), this will clarify you the generics.

Comment: Is the tutorial link broken?

Answer (score 0):

[`public <T> T fromDBObject(Class<T> entityClass, com.mongodb.DBObject dbObject)`](http://morphia.googlecode.com/svn/site/morphia/apidocs/com/google/code/morphia/Morphia.html#fromDBObject%28java.lang.Class,%20com.mongodb.DBObject%29) is a good example of using [*Class Literals as Runtime-Type Tokens*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html). The declaration is very similar to the example near the bottom of the [page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html). One reading might be, "Given a class literal of type **T** named `entityClass` and a `dbObject`, the method `fromDBObject()` returns an object of type **T**. In this case, the symbol **T** stands for the type that the `Class` object represents.